# VBA Expose Word

Tags: vba, excel

I am constantly finding on numerous coding books the work "expose". Here are some phrases:

- The WithEvents keyword *exposes* the events associated with the Application object.
- This model (Document Object Model) *exposes* properties and methods that let you extract information from and also modify the XML.
- The VBA IDE contains an object model that *exposes* key elements of your VBA projects, including the Visual Basic Editor (VBE) itself.

I have googled it with no success and searched my coding books. I seems like an exceedingly strange word to actually pick: expose e.g. ...the WithEvents exposes... what do we mean when we use that word? After my failed search my burning curiosity has just gotten over my restraint of not asking such an easy question on the site....

Comment: Replace "exposes" with "reveals"; Or simply "details".

Comment: Hmmmm i think i'm getting the point.

Comment: I must say i feel a little bit embarrassed

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "exposes" means that it makes it available to use in your code.

If you Dim an Application object in a class module, that object still has events. You just can't see them or manipulate them. When you include `WithEvents`, VBA creates some plumbing to that part of the Application class so your code can use them.

When you set a reference to a library (like MSXML or VBE Extensibility), VBA creates some plumbing to those libraries so your code can reference the classes inside. When you Dim something as `DOMDocoument`, VBA goes through every library you've referenced to see if there's a DOMDocument class. If you don't have a reference to MSXML, it won't find anything and you'll get a compile error. You can also call out which library you want, such as `Dim x as MSXML.DOMDocumnt` and VBA will go directly to that library to look. That's helpful if you have two classes with the same name. If you're automating Word, for example, you may want to Dim something As Word.Range so that it doesn't get confused and use the Range class in the Excel library.